# Have edittext show different keys than what was pressed

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

Im trying to have an edittext which would prompt a keyboard to pop-up when the user selects the edit text. When the user starts typing, it should fill the edittext with the keystrokes that the user puts in... but once a boolean value changes, then the keystrokes that get put will be different than what the user puts in.

If the boolean value is changed, then typing any key in the edittext updates will update, and lets say a "x" gets put in place instead of pressing "z".

The way that I can see about cracking this would be a lengthy keyUp() method that includes ALL keys and puts in their "x" when they get pressed if the boolean is true. Are there any methods or suggestions as to what I could do insead of the lengthy keyUp method. The keyup method doesn't work with

The boolean method that would change would start when a "." gets pressed in the edit test.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [`TextWatcher`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) class. It will allow you to intercept and manipulate user inputs as appropriate (depending on your boolean flag's value) as each character is entered. You can set a TextWatcher on an EditText using the [`addTextChangedListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener(android.text.TextWatcher)) method.

Comment: I have been using the textwatcher, but I'm not sure how to prevent the keystroke from coming up on the edit text and instead putting in a different keystroke.

Comment: You'll need to use the first two TextWatcher callbacks (`beforeTextChanged` and/or `onTextChanged`) to identify the newly-added text, but manipulation should only occur in the `afterTextChanged` callback. If you call `setText` on your EditText from within the `afterTextChanged` callback, I would expect any adjustments to be applied almost instantly (as far as the user is concerned). Heed all the warnings from the `afterTextChanged` documentation though:

Comment: "... be careful not to get yourself into an infinite loop, because any changes you make will cause this method to be called again recursively. (You are not told where the change took place because other afterTextChanged() methods may already have made other changes and invalidated the offsets. But if you need to know here, you can use setSpan(Object, int, int, int) in onTextChanged(CharSequence, int, int, int) to mark your place and then look up from here where the span ended up."

Comment: If you need more detailed help, please modify the OP with the code you have tried so far.

Comment: You cant seem to use a settext() in any of the three methods of textwatcher without it exploding in an infinite loop, which gives me the problem of how to set the text.

Comment: A quick solution would be to switch another boolean flag on (when you trigger an update from afterTextChanged) to allow the first modification to take effect, and then always switch that same flag off if it is currently true. That would prevent the infinite loop, though there may be a neater (and more robust) way to do it.